# find drivers and number of rides with some conditions

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I should write a code to find all drivers(id) and number of trips (n) for those drivers with this Conditions:
n: number of trips that in those trips car's model is x or grater AND trip duration is more than t seconds.

My Models:

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    account = GenericRelation(Account, related_query_name='riders')
    rating = models.FloatField()
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()


class Driver(models.Model):
    account = GenericRelation(Account, related_query_name='drivers')
    rating = models.FloatField()
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class RideRequest(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=car_type_choices)


class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=None)
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=car_type_choices)
    model = models.IntegerField()
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Ride(models.Model):
    pickup_time = models.IntegerField()
    dropoff_time = models.IntegerField()
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request = models.OneToOneField(RideRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    rider_rating = models.FloatField()
    driver_rating = models.FloatField()
```

My Code:

```
drivers = Driver.objects.values('id').annotate(
        travel_time=Sum(Case(
            When(car__ride__pickup_time__isnull=False,
                 then=(F('car__ride__dropoff_time') - F('car__ride__pickup_time'))),
            default=0
        )),
    ).annotate(
        n=Case(
            When(Q(travel_time__gt=t) & Q(car__model__gte=n), then=Count('car__ride')),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
            default=0
        )
    ).values('id', 'n')
```

When i print the result:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'n': 0}, {'id': 2, 'n': 0}, {'id': 2, 'n': 1}, {'id': 3, 'n': 2}, {'id': 4, 'n': 0}, {'id': 5, 'n': 1}, {'id': 5, 'n': 0}]>
```

this is near to real answer but still need do more. for example i have two id=2. it should be one and n associated with it should be 1 (sum of those two n for id=2)

true results:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'n': 0}, {'id': 2, 'n': 1}, {'id': 3, 'n': 2}, {'id': 4, 'n': 0}, {'id': 5, 'n': 1}]>
```

Comment: So you want to find drivers that made *n* travels larger than *k* seconds, right?

Comment: What if a driver made trips with two (or more) cars, and only if these sum up, it is larger than *n*?

Comment: no. i want number of travels a driver made with his/her car which model is greater than x and larger than k seconds. if a driver have car "A" and "B" and both have travels but "A" is less than model x and "B" is greater, we should print 1 not 2. if both have less than t seconds, we should have 0 at all

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem